# Adding list items to another list repeatedly for a certain number of times C# UWP

Tags: c#

I have two lists. The first list is empty, but must be populated a certain number of times. The second list contains a known number of elements, and these elements must be assigned to the first list on rotation until first list is full.

Something like this:

```
List<Product> productList1 = new List<Product>(); // previously populated list. 
List<Product> productList2 = new List<Product>();

for (int i = 0; i < productList1.Count; i++)
{
    Product _product = new Product;
    _product.ProductName = productList1[i].ProductName;
    productList2.Add(_product);
}

int n = productList2.Count;

List<Product> productList3 = new List<Product>;

for (int f = 0; f < n; f++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        productList3.Add(productList2[f];
    }
}

// repeat 'f' loop until i arrives at 60
```

Eg. List2.Count = 4, populate List3 with List2 Products interchangeably until List3 arrives to 60 Products in total.

```
productList2: Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4.
productList3: Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, and so on until reached 60 records.
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, if your original list has n elements, on the n+1 position in your new list, you need to add the first element of the original list, on the n+2 position, the second, on the 2n + 1 the first again and so on.

So you can try this

```
int n = 60; //could be any number
int count = originalList.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    newList.Add(originalList[i % count]); //the remainder of the division
}
```